# RedirectToAction redirecting to wrong URL through Querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

i have this line of code.

```
return RedirectToAction("ManageAllUsers", "Home", new { upnSuffix = ActiveDirectoryHelper.GetUserByUserName(user.UserName).GetUpnSuffix() });
```

i get this result in url:

`home/ManageAllUsers/anyVlue`

instead i want this:

`home/ManageAlluser?upnSuffix=anyvalue`

i dont know what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a parameter named `upnSuffix` in your default route. Default route has a parameter named `id`, you should use that one.

```
return RedirectToAction("ManageAllUsers", "Home", new { id = ActiveDirectoryHelper.GetUserByUserName(user.UserName).GetUpnSuffix() });
```